# MU/Subdomains + Domain Mapping + SSL?

Tags: multisite, subdomains, domain-mapping, ssl

I use a wordpress multisite (subdomain setup + MU Domain Mapping).

mainsite.com

sub1.mainsite.com = sub1.net

sub2.mainsite.com = sub2.net

sub3.mainsite.com = sub3.com

I want to use the ssl in one of the sites (main site or sub mapping domain) for fb apps.

will have no problem with the seo?

What SSL should I choose and what settings should I do to get it right?